# Linq caculate time difference and choose closest one

Tags: c#, linq, datediff

I have list of object like this one:

```
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| ID          | Value      | Time                | 
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 1           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:05:35 |
| 2           | 2          | 2019-03-07 20:06:09 |  
| 5           | 5          | 2019-03-07 20:11:27 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:13:30 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:13:41 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:17:00 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:22:20 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:23:05 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:27:35 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:27:37 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:28:01 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:37:19 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:37:27 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:37:54 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:40:11 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:44:00 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:45:00 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:47:41 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:48:43 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:48:51 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:51:11 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:54:46 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:55:36 |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
```

How to select records 15 minutes apart but records that are more close to the next time?

The result should be something like this:

```
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| ID          | Value      | Time                | 
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
| 1           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:05:35 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:22:20 |
| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:37:19 |
| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:51:11 |
+-------------+------------+---------------------+
```

If the first time is 20:05:35 and next apart 15 min is 20:22:20. The closest time to that is 20:22:20 because difference between them is  00:02:14 and between 20:17:35 is difference 00:02:25. Is there any way to calculate difference and make decision which one is closer to choose?

Comment: added an answer, hope it could help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication132
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Dates> dates = Dates.GetDates();

            var results = dates.GroupBy(x => new DateTime(x.Time.Year, x.Time.Month, x.Time.Day, x.Time.Hour, 15 * (x.Time.Minute / 15), 0).AddMinutes(15))
                .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => x.Key.Subtract(y.Time)).First())
                .ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Dates
    {
        public int ID { get;set;}
        public int Value { get;set;}
        public DateTime Time { get;set;}

        public static List<Dates> GetDates()
        {
            string input =
                "| 1           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:05:35 |\n" +
                "| 2           | 2          | 2019-03-07 20:06:09 |\n" +
                "| 5           | 5          | 2019-03-07 20:11:27 |\n" +
                "| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:13:30 |\n" +
                "| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:13:41 |\n" +
                "| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:17:00 |\n" +
                "| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:22:20 |\n" +
                "| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:23:05 |\n" +
                "| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:27:35 |\n" +
                "| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:27:37 |\n" +
                "| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:28:01 |\n" +
                "| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:37:19 |\n" +
                "| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:37:27 |\n" +
                "| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:37:54 |\n" +
                "| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:40:11 |\n" +
                "| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:44:00 |\n" +
                "| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:45:00 |\n" +
                "| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:47:41 |\n" +
                "| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:48:43 |\n" +
                "| 7           | 1          | 2019-03-07 20:48:51 |\n" +
                "| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:51:11 |\n" +
                "| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:54:46 |\n" +
                "| 8           | 0          | 2019-03-07 20:55:36";
            List<Dates> dates = new List<Dates>();

            string line = "";
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] lineArray = line.Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                Dates newDate = new Dates()
                {
                    ID = int.Parse(lineArray[0]),
                    Value = int.Parse(lineArray[1]),
                    Time = DateTime.Parse(lineArray[2])
                };

                dates.Add(newDate);
            }
            return dates;
        }
    }

}
```

---

The code move the time exactly at the 15 minute interval to next interval.  The smallest resolution of time is 100ns (1 tick) so subtract 1 tick I believe is the correct solution

```
            var results = dates.GroupBy(x => new DateTime(x.Time.Year, x.Time.Month, x.Time.Day, x.Time.Hour, 15 * (x.Time.Minute / 15), 0).AddMinutes(15).AddTicks(-1))
                .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => x.Key.Subtract(y.Time)).First())
                .ToList();
```

---

To group by 15 minutes from start time use this

```
            //tick is 100ns
            const long TICKS_PER_15_MINUTES = 15 * 60 * 10000000L; //minutes, seconds, ticks 

            DateTime minTime = dates.OrderBy(x => x.Time).First().Time;

            List<Dates> results = dates.GroupBy(x => (TICKS_PER_15_MINUTES * ((x.Time.Ticks - minTime.Ticks) / TICKS_PER_15_MINUTES) + TICKS_PER_15_MINUTES - 1))
                .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => x.Key - y.Time.Ticks).First())
                .ToList();
```

---

Finally if you want closest 15 minutes from  min time

```
            //tick is 100ns
            const long TICKS_PER_15_MINUTES = 15 * 60 * 10000000L; //minutes, seconds, ticks 

            DateTime minTime = dates.OrderBy(x => x.Time).First().Time;

            List<Dates> results = dates.GroupBy(x => ((x.Time.Ticks - minTime.Ticks) % TICKS_PER_15_MINUTES) < (TICKS_PER_15_MINUTES / 2)
                ? TICKS_PER_15_MINUTES * ((x.Time.Ticks - minTime.Ticks) / TICKS_PER_15_MINUTES)
                : (TICKS_PER_15_MINUTES * ((x.Time.Ticks - minTime.Ticks) / TICKS_PER_15_MINUTES)) + TICKS_PER_15_MINUTES)
                .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => Math.Abs( x.Key - y.Time.Ticks)).First())
                .ToList();
```

Comment: It seems that this might be ok, but i need to start from first record which is 20:05:35. This is my reference/starting point.

Comment: Do you want every 15 minutes from the start or every 15 minutes interval by time?  Both can be correct.  Over long sampling period it doesn't make a difference. When you have short sampling period than it may make a difference.  Usually your interval (15 minutes) should be much shorter than the sampling period and then it won't make a difference.

Comment: every 15 minutes from start, so in this case start time is 20:05:35, the next one is 20:22:20 which is closer than 20:17:00...

Comment: hm...maybe i missed something but first time in results should be 20:05:35, next one 20:22:20... in this updated code the first one is 20:17:00, second one 20:28:01... see my post with example output.

Comment: Do you want the closest 15 minutes or the next 15 minutes?  The 15 minutes times are 20:05:35, 20:20:35, 20:35:35.  So 20:35:35-20:22:20 = 13:15, 20:20:35 - 20:17:00 = 3:35, and 20:35:35 - 20:28:01 = 7:34.  13:15 is larger than 3:35 unless you are looking for closest instead of next.

Comment: I'm looking for closest, not next.

Comment: yes and no :)... the second and the 4th value are wrong. Second one should be 20:22:17 and 4th 20:51:11. But if you remove dividing TICKS_PER_15_MINUTES by 2 then it is correct. But than I extended existing dataset (see updated post) and than again started wrong picking closest values after 21:11:11 Seems that this is really hard task....

Comment: I must be correct if removing divide by two works.  Then you are wrong.  Using Mod creates a number that is from 0 to 15 minutes.  When the number is less than 7.5 minutes a time is closest to the lower 15 minutes and when it is higher than 7.5 it is closest the the higher 15 minutes.  When you remove the divide by two a time that is mod 14 minutes is then closest to the lower 15 minutes instead of the higher 15 minutes which is only 1 minute away.

Comment: Maybe this will help you to get clear my logic, See this picture https://imgur.com/Xn8xnjF

Comment: Your picture is not worth 1000 words.  The 4 time periods your want to be closest to are : 20:20:35, 20:35:35, 20:50:35, 21:05:35.  Each are exactly 15 minutes apart.

Comment: Correct. But I don't have 20:20:35 or 20:35:35 and so on... so the goal is to take the closest one. So on left side there is 20:22:20. Next 15 min to that is 20:37:20. So if I compare to this one and then if you take look on the left the next one that should be extracted is 20:37:19 because this one is the closest to previous which is 20:37:20. Then we take 20:37:20 + 15 min is 20:52:19. If we look to the left we can see that next one that could match is 20:51:11 because this one is closest to previous which is 20:37:20...and so on. This is my logic behind.

Comment: NO,NO,NO,  Your method will give wrong statistical results.  You never change time periods when getting statistics.   What you are doing is called binning and size of each bin is consistent (not based a previous results).

Comment: So my approach is completely wrong?! I should implement equal width binning?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to fudge the data My probability teacher spent the whole semester discussing random event.After each chapter he asked the class the same question "If I had a perfectly random deck of cards and shuffled the deck one more time.Would the deck be more or less random".With random data you have two choices 1)Put equal number of events in one Bin 2) Put data into equal time periods to get your bins.You are fudging the bins to match the data by restarting the start of the time period. What you are doing to measure the time of an event may be OK,Make sure your start is valid